# "Steel grade identification / confirmation / inspection"

Tags: word-choice

If a company writes in a catalogue that all steel delivered at its pipe-producing plant undergoes testing to ensure that it is of the proper grade, and lists several methods for testing, what is the best way to name the paragraph?

> Steel grade **confirmation**
>   Steel grade **inspection**
>   Steel grade **determination**
>   Steel grade **testing**

I googed all and only several dozens of results came up, so I thought a native speaker might advise me on this count.

Comment: Metal Grade Testing or Metal Grade Confirmation

Comment: Or both :)  https://www.assda.asn.au/technical-info/technical-faqs/testing-for-grade-confirmation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant word here is...

> [**assay**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/assay) *- the testing of **a metal or ore** to determine its ingredients and **quality***

...which can be used as either a noun or a verb. I'm not a metalurgist, but I suspect that in OP's precise context it might be more common to use the form ***assaying***.

---

There may be relevant usages on the [International Meehanite](http://www.meehanite.co.uk/) website (they're a global organisation specializing in foundry quality control).